# Python SQLite3.connect не хочет работать, если до этого был открыт файл с помощью метода open()

Tags: python, sqlite3

Если открыть файл, содержащий пути к файлам БД в формате SQLite:

```py
def get_logs_path(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        log_files =  f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return(log_files)
```

А затем по попробовать открыть по очереди полученные файлы:

```py
log_files = get_logs_path('db_paths.txt')
for log_file in log_files:
    with sqlite3.connect(log_file.replace('\\', '\\\\')) as log:
```

Получаю ошибку: OperationalError: unable to open database file
Если передавать пути к файлу в виде списка (без чтения текстового файла) - все работает замечательно.

Подскажите пожалуйста ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всегда, когда вы вычитываете строки из файла, нужно помнить, что в конце каждой строки будет спецсимвол перевода строки. Если нужно получать строки без этого спецсимвола (как в вашем случае), нужно его удалять. Например, с помощью метода `strip`

Замените

```
log_files =  f.readlines()
```

на

```
log_files = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]
```

PS: И, кстати, если вы открываете файл в контекстном менеджере `with`, то закрывать файл уже не обязательно - контекстный менеджер сам об этом позаботится.

Comment: Кроме этого, у него замена \ на \\, т.е. был путь `C:\Users\txt.sqlite` станет `C:\\Users\\txt.sqlite`. Это не должно сломать код, но такие пути очень странные